# How to write custom obj_create and obj_update in django tasty pie

Tags: jquery, django, tastypie, put

I am trying to override obj_create and obj_update in Django tasty pie

```
class HomeTasksResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = HomeTasks.objects.filter(is_deleted = False)
        resource_name = 'tasks'
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = MyAuthentication()
        excludes = [ 'datetime']
        allowed_methods = ['get','post','put','patch']
        serializer = urlencodeSerializer()
        always_return_data = True
    def obj_update(self, bundle, **kwargs):        
        taskForm = HomeTasksForm(bundle.data,instance = bundle.obj)                 
        if taskForm.is_valid():  

            messages.success(bundle.request,"The task is updated successfully")            
            returnData =  super(HomeTasksResource, self).obj_update(bundle,user = bundle.request.user,id = bundle.obj.id)

            return returnData 

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs): 

        taskForm = HomeTasksForm(bundle.data)
        if taskForm.is_valid() and bundle.obj is None:    
            messages.success(bundle.request,"The task is successfully added")            
            returnData =  super(HomeTasksResource, self).obj_create(bundle,user = bundle.request.user)                

            return returnData
```

The above is working, but for some strange reason, for every update/put call the "create is also being called." i.e. for put both the functions are running. What am I doing wrong ?
Am using jquery and latest version of tastypie.

Answer (score 2):

The default `put_detail` view of tastypie calls `obj_update` but falls back to `obj_create` if the object is not found or can't figure out which one to update. So for every new entry through put, both `obj_update` and `obj_create` would be called. However, for an existing entry ideally only `obj_update` should be called.

> ```
> def put_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
>     """
>     Either updates an existing resource or creates a new one with the
>     provided data.
>
>     Calls ``obj_update`` with the provided data first, but falls back to
>     ``obj_create`` if the object does not already exist.
>
>     If a new resource is created, return ``HttpCreated`` (201 Created).
>     If ``Meta.always_return_data = True``, there will be a populated body
>     of serialized data.
>
>     If an existing resource is modified and
>     ``Meta.always_return_data = False`` (default), return ``HttpNoContent``
>     (204 No Content).
>     If an existing resource is modified and
>     ``Meta.always_return_data = True``, return ``HttpAccepted`` (200
>     OK).
>     """
>     deserialized = self.deserialize(request, request.body, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
>     deserialized = self.alter_deserialized_detail_data(request, deserialized)
>     bundle = self.build_bundle(data=dict_strip_unicode_keys(deserialized), request=request)
>
>     try:
>         updated_bundle = self.obj_update(bundle=bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
>
>         if not self._meta.always_return_data:
>             return http.HttpNoContent()
>         else:
>             updated_bundle = self.full_dehydrate(updated_bundle)
>             updated_bundle = self.alter_detail_data_to_serialize(request, updated_bundle)
>             return self.create_response(request, updated_bundle)
>     except (NotFound, MultipleObjectsReturned):
>         updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle=bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
>         location = self.get_resource_uri(updated_bundle)
>
>         if not self._meta.always_return_data:
>             return http.HttpCreated(location=location)
>         else:
>             updated_bundle = self.full_dehydrate(updated_bundle)
>             updated_bundle = self.alter_detail_data_to_serialize(request, updated_bundle)
>             return self.create_response(request, updated_bundle, response_class=http.HttpCreated, location=location)
> ```